# How to programmatically click on a EIT Lightbox hyperling in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, javascript, events

On my webpage Im using EIT Lightbox to display images. I need to click on the Lightbox hyper link by code. I have tried the following

```
body.Attributes.Add("onLoad", "document.getElementById(\"lbh1\").click()\n");
body.Attributes.Add("onload", "eval(document.getElementById(\"lbh1\").href);\n");
```

But neither seems to work.
If I use the following code

```
body.Attributes.Add("onload", "alert('popup');\n");
```

The alert is displayed

Is there another way to do the click?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this doesn't work in Firefox.  Check out this article: http://lifescaler.com/2008/04/simulating-mouse-clicks-in-javascript/ or just do a Google search on simulating mouse events and/or clicks.